# ERROR 1064 (42000) - MySQL error in INSERT ... SELECT query

Tags: mysql, sql

As part of a MySQL trigger I'm writing, I've got an INSERT ... SELECT query that is returning :

> ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 7: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near `'pp2 (curr_code, pricing_id, pid, title, startdate, enddate, priority, enabled) S'` at line 33

```
INSERT INTO product_pricing pp2 (curr_code, pricing_id, pid, title, startdate, enddate, priority, enabled) 
SELECT cc, `pp1`.`pricing_id`, `pp1`.`pid`, `pp1`.`title`, `pp1`.`startdate`, `pp1`.`enddate`, `pp1`.`priority`, `pp1`.`enabled` 
FROM product_pricing pp1 
WHERE pp1.pp_id = NEW.pp_id 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE pp2.pp_id=(SELECT newppid := pp2.pp_id);
```

I'm not sure if it's the **cc** part?  That's a declared variable in the trigger but it should work given that you should be able to do a *SELECT 'hello', t.col1 FROM table t*

Any suggestions as to what the error is greatly received.

Comment: First thing : `INSERT INTO [...] VALUES [...]` is the syntax. Where is your `VALUES` ?

Comment: @Kabulan0lak There's also `INSERT INTO ... SELECT`. The `SELECT` provides the values.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar Hum ok I didn't know. Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [INSERT syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert.html) doesn't allow for aliases.

```
INSERT INTO table [ ( column [, ...] ) ]
    { DEFAULT VALUES | VALUES ( { expression | DEFAULT } [, ...] ) [, ...] | query }
    [ RETURNING * | output_expression [ [ AS ] output_name ] [, ...] ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove that `pp2` from the INSERT query